# What is the base directory for Zend ViewModel setTemplate?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

I'm trying to load a different view depending on the value taken from a Regex route, but I can't get the ViewModel to load the template

```
public function viewAction()
{
    $page = $this->params()->fromRoute()["page"];

    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTemplate('module/Base/view/base/index/$page');

    return $view;
}
```

I'm following the conventional module setup:

```
Base
|- config
|  |- module.config.php
|- src
|  |- Base
|     |- Controller
|        |- IndexController.php
|- view
   |- base
   |  |- index
   |     |- index.phtml
   |     |- other.phtml
   |- layout
```

And my view_manager configuration is:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'        => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'error/404'            => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'          => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

I've tried all sort of values in the path passed to setTemplate, but I just keep getting the application error message, but no error log or details (that may be because I haven't figured out displaying errors properly). I have confirmed that `$page` is getting the name of the template correctly from the URL, and the template is in the correct directory.

So, where does ViewModel start looking for templates?

I've tried:

```
$view->setTemplate('$page.phtml');
$view->setTemplate('$page');
$view->setTemplate('base/index/$page.phtml');
$view->setTemplate('base/index/$page');
$view->setTemplate('module/Base/view/base/index/$page.phtml');
$view->setTemplate('module/Base/view/base/index/$page');
```

Comment: ugh - numpty... I should be using double quotes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each module that requires view scripts should have a `view_manager` key in `module.config.php`

You have two choices when registering view scripts.

```
'view_manager' => [
    'template_map' => [
        'module-name/foo/bar' => __DIR__ . '/../view/foo/bar.phtml',
        'custom_view_template_name' => __DIR__ . '/../view/some/other/path/bar.phtml',
    ],
    'template_path_stack' => [
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ],
],
```

**Template Path Stack**

This represents a collection (stack) of paths that the view resolver will try to find paths from.

The view scripts that you set on the view models in the controller would then be relative to this directory path. This option saves you time by 'automatically' resolving view script paths using a common naming convention.

For example, if you have `FooModule` and the file `FooModule/view/foo-module/index/index.phtml` the template path that should be used in the controller would be `foo-module/index/index`.

**Template Map**

A one to one mapping of template name to template path. This means the template path is exactly the same as the array key.

You should try to favor this method as using the `template_path_stack` incurs a slight performance hit as the view scripts need to be resolved at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I am using it like this:

after the view folder inside your module add the path. So I assume yours is

```
view->setTemplate('base/index/$page');
```

This should do the trick.